# Daily financial, economic and world (television) news in German

Tags: learning

I hope this question isn't off-topic, since this website is about language-specific questions. This seemed like the site closest to my post. :)

For the purpose of exposing myself to the spoken German language, I want to watch the news in German, as a complement to my grammar, vocabulary and reading endeavors.

I am looking for (video) episodes of a news channel, which reports world-, financial- and economic news on a daily basis in German.

I took a look on a few news sites ([zdf](https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten), [dw](https://www.dw.com/de/29062018-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-44453006)) but have not yet been able to pin down the link to a page listing the "missed episodes" of a news channel of my aforementioned preference. That is, *with* video.

Comment: Comments are not for replacing answers; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79647/discussion-on-question-by-musse-redi-daily-financial-economic-and-world-televi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch the past episodes of the [Tagesthemen (en.wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagesthemen)  here:

http://www.tagesschau.de/sendung/tagesthemen/index.html

autoplays the current episode, below you can find the older ones.

Also, if you are interested in the Austrian variety of German have a look at the [ZIB / Zeit im Bild (en.wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeit_im_Bild) here:

https://tvthek.orf.at/profiles/genre/ZIB/2703825#scroll

Please be aware that for ... reasons ... the episodes are usually only available for some days.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Youtube: tagesschau
They are from ARD, the first national Television station in Germany

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

German Euronews channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCACdxU3VrJIJc7ujxtHWs1w

Deutsche Welle: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMIgOXM2JEQ2Pv2d0_PVfcg

But also Arte DE if you're more into docos: https://www.youtube.com/user/ARTEde